# How can I access multiple layers in my url using asp-controller or asp-action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, model-view-controller

On my site I have a page on `/Home/Index`

This is the index page in my HomeController.

To reach this page I have the link:

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
</li>
```

I want to add the same link for a different page, but this page is located on /Products/Food/Index.
I tried the following:

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Products/Food" asp-action="Index">Food</a>
</li>
```

But this results in `/Products%2FFood/Index` in the URL bar.

What can I do to reach this page using the way of referencing pages?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```html
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Products/Food/Index">Food</a>
```

It is basically same with using anchor tag with asp-*, those are tag helpers

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to change the folder structure like create Area "Products" in that Products add Controller "FoodController.cs" then add a view "Index".

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Products" asp-controller="Food" asp-action="Index">Food</a>
</li>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89KpD.png)

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89KpD.png)